Dapper with MariaDB stored procedure with UUID type parameters
I'm trying to call stored procedure with parameter of type UUID from Dapper and getting the exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at MySqlConnector.Core.TypeMapper.GetMySqlDbType(String typeName, Boolean unsigned, Int32 length) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/TypeMapper.cs:line 187

This is my Dapper parameter:
    var t_value = Guid.Parse("0198be44-f52a-48fe-9855-054a484c5d2d");   
  //var t_value = "0198be44-f52a-48fe-9855-054a484c5d2d";
    var cmdParams = new DynamicParameters();
    cmdParams.Add("p_t", t_value, DbType.Guid);

And this is my simple test procedure:
procedure test_uuid(IN p_t uuid)

Thing is, it has no problem with uuid from tables and select, it maps on Guid of my c# model class. If I change procedure parameter type to char(36), it works, but uuid for procedures is strict requirement for us.
Am I missing something? Is there any way to work it out?

recommend creating an issue on GH Drapper.
